# How to pass access token generated in one request to all request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I had created a access token via first api call that i want to use in all other api call, it works for next call but it fails for third api call.

I am using Regular expression extractor, where i have created a variable named token, it passes in second api call in request header , but for third api call it is not taking it (it takes second api's response in the request)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), if you have the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) at the same level as all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - it will be applied to **all Samplers**, therefore when your `Login` request gets executed - your `token` variable gets overwritten with the `Login` sampler response.

If you want to extract the data only from the `Login Token` sampler - you need to make the Regular Expression Extractor **a child** of the `Login Token` sampler

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response, it works for me.

Comment: Hi need one more help : how to user this token for new thread group ?

Comment: Normally you should not be using the token across different Thread Groups as they represent different groups of virtual users. However if you must - you can use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to convert JMeter Variable into a JMeter property in 1st thread group and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function  to read the value in 2nd thread group. Another option is [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks a ton.... Done... Need to add BeanShellAssertion in first thread group with ${__setProperty(token,${token})}   and in second thread group ${__property(token)}. Once again thanks alot for helping me.